# Calculating Polynomial Regression Confidence Bands

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, polynomial

I have $N$ samples with known standard deviation: $(x_i, y_i \pm \sigma_i)$. I need to use order-$p$ least-squares polynomial regression to create confidence bands for $\hat y(x)$. I know R can do this automatically, but I'd like to be able to explain the algorithm in a publication and also be able to calculate the $\hat y=0$ roots of the confidence band. I've also seen simple algorithms for doing this with data without known $\sigma_i$ ([e.g.](https://stat.duke.edu/~tjl13/s101/slides/unit6lec3H.pdf)), but I'd prefer to take advantage of the known $\sigma_i$ estimates.

I implemented the algorithm for polynomial confidence bands from the [OriginLab help pages](http://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/PR-Algorithm), but the resulting bands are wider than I expect. Specifically, if I increase the number of samples in a fixed $x$ domain, the band stays the same width.

I think the problem is $\chi^2$ in Eq. 24. I understand that it's there to account for departures from the model larger than $\sigma_i$, but since $\chi^2$ grows as $N$ and $\mathbf{C}$ decreases as $1/N$, the uncertainty term $\chi^2 \mathbf{xCx}$ remains roughly constant. Should this be $\chi^2/N$ instead of $\chi^2$?

Also, is there a better reference available for this problem? I'd like to be able to cite something that's reasonably credible but still accessible to people (like me) with limited stats background.

Comment: There are (at least) two kinds of "bands": confidence intervals for parameter estimation and prediction intervals which might well be described as "confidence bands for ŷ (x)". Prediction intervals should not decrease in width when N is increased.

Comment: @Dwin yes they should ... just not very much

Comment: @DWin, your point is well taken---it makes sense that the 95% *prediction* interval would narrow to a finite limit based on the variance of the samples. I'm interested in the confidence intervals of the true $y(x)$, *not* prediction intervals.

Comment: No. Prediction intervals will be as wide as the population variance makes them. The usual "confidence intervals" are on the mean value of Y conditional on X. The CI for the mean or the conditional mean will narrow as the sample size increases. Your terminology is not c/w that notion. You need to clarify what is mean by "true Y". I would not use the expression "true y(x)" to refer to the mean of y.

Comment: @DWin I'm looking for the mean of $y$ conditional on $x$. Confidence intervals, on the mean of $y$, not prediction bands.

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment; prediction intervals are based on a variance with two components, one for the variance of the data and one for the uncertainty in the mean. As $n$ increases, the first stays constant while the second gets smaller ... and as a result, the width of the prediction interval actually reduces as $n$ increases (but to a limiting value >0).